# How to generate arrays from an array list in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I'd like to generate arrays with the name of the values in another array like this

```
$array_names = array("name1","name2","name3",...);
```

So, for each item inside of my `$array_names`.  I'd like to generate an array with the name of the items like this

```
$name1, $name2, $name3 ... etc...
```

I tried something like

```
foreach( $array_names as $name){
    $name = array();
//or like this:
    $."$name" = array();
}
```

but clearly, I am kinda lost... Any idea?

Comment: Bad idea.  Just use a multidimensional array.  But there is `extract()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close :)

```
foreach($array_names as $name) $$name = array();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Adelphia (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array_names = array("name1","name2","name3");

foreach( $array_names as $name){
   $$name = array();
}
```

To test:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_defined_vars())
```